# Problem applying the Divergence Theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Let $S={(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : z=x^2-y^2,x^2+y^2=\leq 1}$ oriented upwards. Find the flux of $F(x,y,z)=(x,y,1)$ through $S$.

With the parametrization $x(r,\theta)=(r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta,r^2\cos2\theta), 0\leq r\leq1,0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ we get

$$\iint_S F dS= \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}-2r^3\cos2\pi + r \ \ d\theta dr= \pi$$

But then

$$\iiint_R \text{div }F \ dV=2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi} 2r^3 \cos 2\pi \ d\theta dr=0$$

Where did I go wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply the divergence theorem, you are computing the flux across the *total boundary* of the region $R$. Since you didn't write down the *triple* integral, it's hard to read your mind. (So you should be including lots more details if you expect us to find your errors!) What is the region $R$?  Does it not include a base and cylindrical sides, along with the surface $S$ on the top?

Comment: Ah, I see. The surface doesn't delimit a solid region... So the first flux integral is correct then?

Comment: I can't answer that unless you show me your work. I can't imagine where all the $\cos\theta$, $\sin\theta$, $\cos 2\theta$, $\sin 2\theta$ went and why you type $\cos 2\pi$.

Comment: OK, I just did all the computation. That $\cos 2\pi$ was supposed to be $\cos 2\theta$, right?  So, yes, it appears your computation was correct ...